# Using the Aurelia Redirect class

Tags: aurelia

I've added an authorize pipeline step to my router. Everything works fine, but when I use the `Redirect` class to point the user to the login page, it takes a URL as its argument. I'd prefer to pass in the route name as I would if I were using `Router.navigateToRoute()`. Is this possible?

```
@inject(AuthService)
class AuthorizeStep {
    constructor (authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    run (navigationInstruction, next) {
        if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.auth)) {
            if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
                return next.cancel(new Redirect('url-to-login-page')); // Would prefer to use the name of route; 'login', instead.
            }
        }

        return next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some Googling I found the `Router.generate()` method which takes a router name (and optional params) and returns the URL. I've now updated my authorize step to the following:

```
@inject(Router, AuthService)
class AuthorizeStep {
    constructor (router, authService) {
        this.router = router;
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    run (navigationInstruction, next) {
        if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.auth)) {
            if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
                return next.cancel(new Redirect(this.router.generate('login')));
            }
        }

        return next();
    }
}
```

Edit: After some more googling I found the `RedirectToRoute` class;

```
import { RedirectToRoute } from 'aurelia-router';
```

...

```
return next.cancel(new RedirectToRoute('login'));
```